# Is my system vulnerable to Log4Shell vulnerability?

Tags: java, logging

I'm an end user with Windows 11. I don't have JDK or JRE installed. Is my machine vulnerable to log4j exploits? If so, how is the exploit possible?

Comment: This might be a better fit for security.stackexchange.com (although it is certainly on-topic here as well)

Comment: If you don’t have the Java VM installed, it’s impossible for you to run any application, that might implement log4j which means you are not vulnerable.

Comment: @VijaymahanteshSattigeri - Without specifics about which Java applications you have installed, it will be impossible to determine if your machine is vulnerable, you should [edit] your question to include the necessary information required to answer your question.  The vulnerability only exists if your running a server Java application.

Comment: ZDNN - Why your first take on this vulnerability may not be correct.    https://www.techrepublic.com/article/log4j-vulnerability-your-hot-take-is-wrong/?ftag=TRE684d531&bhid=23164040498209351948461508422926&mid=13622506&cid=712212189

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't run any software that's using Java you're fine (at least for this exploit).

Do however keep in mind that there's a lot of things that use Java under the hood while having a native compiled application to start things and have an embedded JVM. Those are potentially affected. Examples of this are for example Jetbrains CLion and PyCharm, both are Java applications.

Of course the only such applications that are vulnerable to actual attack are those that can be accessed from the internet (or by an active intruder on your network, in which case you have a far bigger problem.

The aforementioned Jetbrains products aren't among those btw, they are just examples of things that run Java under water when the end user may not even be aware of it. Nor do they rely on Log4J2, they use another logging solution internally.

Were you running say Jira or Confluence, or other products like that, you might be vulnerable and should check with your suppliers.

Comment: Theoretically a user could exploit themselves, but that would have to require the Java application, NOT sanitize their inputs into log4j in order to exploit themselves. The exploit outside of a server instance is a big fat nothing burger. Just don’t be putting the required strings into Java applications and you cannot be exploited by said exploit on a Windows 11 machine that isn’t running a java application acting like a server like Minecraft.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that this is not so easy to determine.  There are lots of systems and applications that have included the Log4j2 service.  The current list of systems known to be affected, unaffected or currently under investigation is at https://github.com/cisagov/log4j-affected-db#software-list

Comment: Doesn't this vulnerability affect servers more then clients- ie would it be safe to say that an end user is reasonably secure provided they are not running any servers.   Per https://www.randori.com/blog/cve-2021-44228/  "Effectively, any scenario that allows a **remote connection to supply arbitrary data that is written to log files** by an application utilizing the Log4j library is susceptible to exploitation" would imply that this is more a server problem.   Im not saying its impossible to exploit on some clients, but it would be much harder and more niche.

Comment: @davidgo: It depends; it's entirely reasonable that a client might keep debug logs of information it receives from server (plenty of those in %TEMP%), and if that information is user-submitted – [like chat messages](https://www.pcmag.com/opinions/critical-exploit-for-apache-log4j2-could-be-far-reaching-proves-real-in) – it'll affect clients just the same. Of course, fewer desktop programs are written in Java to begin with, but... that's what the question is about, anyway.

Comment: @user1686 - A client that doesn’t even have the Java VM installed? The vulnerability is within log4j, and while a client application could implement logging using that library, it requires the client to have the Java VM installed

Comment: @Ramhound: That doesn't mean the user has to have installed it actively – many programs do bundle their own JVM right with the app, without using a separate installer for it. (I.e. it doesn't show up in "Add/Remove Programs", it's just a java.exe etc)

Comment: @user1686 - If that’s the case, and Java applications are being ran, then the question should be clarified

Comment: @Ramhound: But I think that's exactly what OP *is asking about.* They haven't *explicitly* installed Java, and they're *asking* about whether there are other ways the machine can be vulnerable, with the answer being what jwenting has posted.

Comment: @user1686 - Which seems to suggest the question is too broad and cannot be reasonably answered without specifics about which applications they have installed.

Answer (score 0):

### UPDATE: 2021-12-18...

Remember to always check for the latest information from the resources listed below

**[CVE-2021-45105](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2021-45105)**... 2.16.0 and 2.12.2 are no longer valid remediations! The current fixing versions are 2.17.0 (Java 8) and 2.12.3 (Java 7). All other Java versions have to take the stop gap approach (removing/deleting JndiLookup.class file from the log4j-core JAR.
I have updated my message below accordingly.

---

**Answering the question directly:**
Go to [Reddit thread: log4j_0day_being_exploited](https://www.reddit.com/r/blueteamsec/comments/rd38z9/log4j_0day_being_exploited/)
and <kbd>cntl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> for `Vendor Advisories` and search those lists to see if you use any of that software. If you do and an update is available, update it.

Then go to the same website and <kbd>cntl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> for `.class and .jar recursive hunters`
Run the program from the repo listed there. If it finds anything, remediate it.

- More resources

  - https://www.reddit.com/r/blueteamsec/comments/rd38z9/log4j_0day_being_exploited/

    - This one has TONS of useful info including detectors, even more resource links, very easy to understand remediation steps, and more
  - https://www.cisa.gov/uscert/apache-log4j-vulnerability-guidance
  - https://github.com/cisagov/log4j-affected-db
  - https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/security.html

---

**Remediation:**
**[CVE-2021-45046](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2021-45046) ... [CVE-2021-44228](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2021-44228) ... [CVE-2021-45105](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2021-45105)**
While most people that need to know probably already know enough to do what they need to do, I thought I would still put this just in case...

- Follow the guidance in those resources... it may change, but

#### As of 2021-12-18

It's basically

- Remove log4j-core JAR files if possible

  - From both running machines for immediate fix AND
  - in your source code / source code management files to prevent future builds / releases / deployments from overwriting the change
- If that is not possible (due to a dependency), upgrade them

  - If you are running Java8, then you can upgrade to log4j 2.17.0+
  - If you are running an earlier version of Java, then you can upgrade to log4j 2.12.3
  - If you are running an older version of Java, then you need to upgrade to the newest version of Java, and then use the newest version of Log4J
  - Again, these changes have to happen both on running machine and in code
- If neither of those are possible for some reason... then there is the NON-remediation stop gap of removing the JndiLookup.class file from the log4j-core JARs.

  - There is a one-liner for the stop gap option on Linux using the `zip` command that comes packaged with most Linux distros by default.

    - `zip -q -d "$LOG4J_JAR_PATH" org/apache/logging/log4j/core/lookup/JndiLookup.class`
  - At time of writing, most of the guides online for the stop gap option on Windows say to do the following (again... assuming you can't do one of the remove JAR or upgrade options above):

    - Install something like 7-zip
    - Locate all of your log4j-core JAR files and for each one do the following...
    - Rename the JAR to change the extension to `.zip`
    - Use 7-zip to unzip the JAR (which now has a `.zip` extension)
    - Locate and remove the JndiLookup.class file from the unzipped folder

      - The path is `\\path\\to\\unzippedFolder\\org\\apache\\logging\\log4j\\core\\lookup\\JndiLookup.class`
    - Delete the old JAR file (which now has an extension of .zip)
    - Use 7-zip to RE-zip the folder
    - Rename the new .zip folder to change the extension to `.jar`
  - There are also some options to use Power Shell

    - [Reddit thread: log4j_0day_being_exploited](https://www.reddit.com/r/blueteamsec/comments/rd38z9/log4j_0day_being_exploited/)
    - <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> for "PowerShell"

This is fine if you only have 1 or 2 JAR files to deal with and you don't mind installing 7-zip or you have PowerShell available to do it. However, if you have lots of JAR files, or if you don't want to install 7-zip and don't have access to Power Shell, I created an open-source VBS script that will do it for you without needing to install any additional software. https://github.com/CrazyKidJack/Windowslog4jClassRemover

Read the README and the Release Notes https://github.com/CrazyKidJack/Windowslog4jClassRemover/releases/latest

Answer (score 0):

Good explanation of the exploit from Computerphile.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Opqgwn8TdlM